# Access denied on TeamCity VCS update

Tags: teamcity, perforce

I have some trouble getting the VCS of teamcity work.

I'm using perforce and the TC-Server should be configured correct, but when running the project I'm getting the error:

> [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Error while applying patch: Failed to change text file: C:\Projects\BuildSrv7... C:\Projects\BuildSrv7.. (Access denied)

I checked the Settings and everybody has full rights in the directory.

And idea, what to do, or how this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem. In my case it was an error with Clientmapping configuration.

Teamcity default was "//depot/... //team-city-agent/.."
I changed it to "//depot/... //team-city-agent/..." with 3 dots on the end and it worked. Thats the normal way of perforce with 3 dots.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [known issues](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-ConflictingSoftware). Most likely it's your case.